# Mac mini not showing picture after changing resolution

Tags: macos, display, mac-mini, resolution, bug

I just updated my 2018 Intel Mac mini to macOS 12.3, and after updating I tried changing the resolution on my monitor, but got a blank screen after the log-in screen that would normally show my desktop after entering my password.

Display is Samsung CRG9 using a Thunderbolt 3 to DisplayPort 1.4 cable. Tried the cable and monitor with my M1 MacBook Air (also running 12.3) and had no issues whatsoever, so I know it’s the Mac mini.

Restarting my Mac several times does not fix the display situation.

This link to try and fix the issue helped in safe mode only.

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/picture-change-resolution-mchlp2660/mac

It did allow me to see my desktop in safe mode and I followed all of the directions,  but after I restarted it normally as the help page suggested, I still get a blank screen on my monitor. Not really sure what to do here, but any help would be appreciated.

Are there other steps that may help restore the display on the mini?

Comment: What model is the monitor? Are you using the builtin HDMI jack?

Comment: It’s the Samsung CRG9, I’m using a Thunderbolt 3 to DisplayPort 1.4 cable. Tried the cable and monitor with my M1 MacBook Air and had no issues whatsoever, so I know it’s the Mac mini. No idea what’s causing this issue but it only started after I updated to macOS 12.3.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Same model Mac Mini and same display. Getting it to run full resolution was always a bit wonky (only some DP adaptors work). But yeah 12.3 seems to have messed it up. While my secondary USB Type-C display still works. Also the monitor works fine with the same adaptor on a M1 Pro MBP

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing when upgrading my Mac Mini 2018 to MacOS 12.3 yesterday, I was unable to change the resolution of my LG 4K monitor (DP) for some specific screen resolutions, blank screen each time. Did some research today and found a way to solve this issue, you just need to reset the Mac mini NVRAM and SMC and then everything should come back to normal. The official steps are available on the web.

Comment: I would guess SMC is not needed here. Can anyone try just NVRAM and edit or answer or report which is needed?

Comment: For me SMC resets just get the display back in the lower 3840x1080 resolution. Any display settings change after that will black out the screen again.